# resolving a promise with EventListener

Tags: javascript

I am working on a popup div and I would like to have a promise attached to the animation so I can do something after the popup ended.

My approach does not work because I could not find a way to pass the promise to the function on the event handler. Seems you cannot use bind here. I have tried and although I can resolve the promise, I cannot remove the event handler

What would be a different solution here?

```
function EventListenerForPopUp() {
    this.removeEventListener("animationend", EventListenerForPopUp );
    this.Show.resolve();
}   

function ShowHideDiv() {        
    this.Show = function () { 
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            this.Div.addEventListener("animationend", EventListenerForPopUp, false);
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: addEventListener is used to set an event on an object or DOM element. It takes a callback, which is the "old" way of doing things. Isn't there a simple way to wrap addEventListener in a Promise, so that 'then' and 'catch' can be used? I would love to have this kind of consistency available in my programs.

This question doesn't seem to have an acceptable answer as yet, even after 2 years.

Comment: Of course, the obvious difference is that the same event can occur again and again, while a single asynchronous operation happens only once. Promises have a single Pending state which changes only once to a Fulfilled or Rejected state. This is not a good match with events, which occur repeatedly. It is also not a good match for setInterval, which occurs repeatedly, but is a good match for setTimeout, which occurs once.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You do not need to pass the promise to the event handler, you need to pass the `resolve` callback:

```
function EventListenerForPopUp(resolve) {
            this.removeEventListener("animationend", EventListenerForPopUp );
            resolve();
}   

// [...]

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            this.Div.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
                EventListenerForPopUp.call(this, resolve);
            }, false);
```

This looks a bit ugly to me, maybe you can look at something like this:

```
var div = this.Div;
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    div.addEventListener("animationend", function animationendListener() {
        div.removeEventListener("animationend", animationendListener);
        //call any handler you want here, if needed
        resolve();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. the first option did not remove the event listener.

Comment: I use the second approach. Have seen some remarks about not using local variables to carry this objects. but on this case haven't figure out a way not to do it

Comment: _the first option did not remove the event listener_

I guess this is why the 1st solution looks a bit ugly to the author.

Comment: this second approach helped me to receive the promises properply up vote from me

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, we can create a reusable utility function as a means of creating a promise from any DOM event:

```
const createPromiseFromDomEvent = (eventTarget, eventName, run?) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const handleEvent = () => {
            eventTarget.removeEventListener(eventName, handleEvent);

            resolve();
        };

        eventTarget.addEventListener(eventName, handleEvent);

        try {
            if (run) run();
        catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
```

Example usage (with an MSE source buffer):

```
await createPromiseFromDomEvent(
    sourceBuffer,
    'update',
    () => sourceBuffer.remove(3, 10)
);
```

Depending on the situation, the `run` parameter may be needed to provide custom code to trigger the async operation (as above), or omitted if we know the operation has already started.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to abstract an externally controlled promise as a reusable function -

```js
function thread () {
  let resolve, reject
  const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    resolve = res
    reject = rej
  })
  return [promise, resolve, reject]
}

function customPrompt(form) {
  const [prompt, resolve] = thread()
  form.yes.addEventListener("click", _ => resolve(true), {once: true})
  form.no.addEventListener("click", _ => resolve(false), {once: true})
  return prompt
}

customPrompt(document.forms.myform)
  .then(response => console.log("response:", response))
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="button" name="yes" value="yes" />
  <input type="button" name="no" value="no" />
</form>
```

You can use `async` and `await` if you wanted -

```js
async function main () {
  const response = await customPrompt(document.forms.myform)
  console.log("response:", response)
}
```

You could easily add a timeout by modifying `customPrompt` -

```js
function customPrompt(form) {
  const [prompt, resolve, reject] = thread()
  form.yes.addEventListener("click", _ => resolve(true), {once: true})
  form.no.addEventListener("click", _ => resolve(false), {once: true})
  
  // timeout after 30 seconds
  setTimeout(reject, 30000, Error("no response"))
  return prompt
}
```

For other creative uses of `thread`, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628301/633183).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer gets close but fails to implement the reusability of the event handler. Normally you are expected to add an event handler callback to the event listener and use it multiple times without needing to remove it and add a new one per event. You just need to refresh the "resolve exposing promise" not the handler. Such as

```js
async function* iterableEventListener(element, event){
  let _resolve,
      _promise = new Promise(v => _resolve = v);
  element.addEventListener( event
                          , e => ( _resolve(e)
                                 , _promise = new Promise(v => _resolve = v)
                                 )
                          );
  while (true) yield _promise;
}

let myButton    = document.getElementById("boru"),
    eventStream = iterableEventListener(myButton,"click");

(async () => {
  for await (let event of eventStream) {
    console.log(event.type);
    console.log("Button Clicked..!");
  }
})();
```

```html
<button id="boru">Click Me</button>
```