# Using setInterval() with a .map method in array and returning as a promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, promise, timer

I have a function that takes a list of IDs, converts them into an array URLS, then uses the map function to fire a fetch request. It works great but it fires too fast and the provider throws errors because we hit the API too often. I need to set an interval for the request but every time I do, it doesn't really work. Ideas?

```
async function getReports(reportIDs) {
    const urls = reportIDs.map(id => `https://api.data.com/api/v1/report/${id}/?include_datasets=true`);
    const requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'api-key': key }
    }).then(res => res.json()));
    
    const responses = await Promise.all(requests).catch(err => console.error(err));
    return responses;
}
```

I use a promise so I can `await` the results of the function inside another function to transform the datasets.

Ideas?

Comment: Do you want an interval or wait for a response before firing the next request?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If node, there is a fairly lightweight npm package called [bottleneck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck) which will throttle requests. It works quite well and is widely used. Or you can look at that and roll your own.

Comment: Worked great 

`
async function getReports(reportIDs) {
 const urls = reportIDs.map(id => 'https://api.data.com/api/v1/report/${id}/?include_datasets=true');
 const requests = urls.map(url => limiter.schedule(()=>fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { 'api-key': key }
 }).then(res => res.json())));
`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info). Posts that simply recommend a library can be written as a comment. If you are interested in how you might solve a problem like this on your own, please see the answer I provided.

Comment: @Thank you for taking the time to provide a pure js solution for future readers. Your answer is excellent; lacking time to elucidate, I gave an immediate response which solved the problem (and pointed to an example) allowing the OP to move on to what was important. I agree, especially when not writing one-use utility code, that a few lines is preferable to using an entire library. I also agree that error handling, timeouts, and retry would be critical features for many applications. Sometimes it's important to teach, other times to point and move on; Thankfully, Stack facilitates both.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I agree with your points, I was only suggesting that your post was made as a comment :D

Answer (score 6):

*“Simplicity is a great virtue but it requires hard work to achieve it and education to appreciate it. And to make matters worse: complexity sells better.”* — [Edsger W. Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra)

The accepted "lightweight" solution is nearly **20,000** lines of code and depends on both CoffeeScript and Lua. What if you could trade all of that for just 50 lines of JavaScript?

Let's say we have some `job` that takes some amount of time to compute some result -

```js
async function job(x) {
  // job consumes some time
  await sleep(rand(5000))
  // job computes a result
  return x * 10
}

Promise.all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(job))
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```js
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
```

This runs all twelve (12) jobs at once. If these were requests to a remote, some connections could be rejected because you are flooding the server with too much simultaneous traffic. By modeling a `Pool` of threads, we control the flow of the parallelized jobs -

```js
// my pool with four threads
const pool = new Pool(4)

async function jobQueued(x) {
  // wait for pool thread
  const close = await pool.open()
  // run the job and close the thread upon completion
  return job(x).then(close)
}

Promise.all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(jobQueued))
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```js
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
```

Functions should be small and do just one thing. This makes it easier to write individual features and promotes a higher degree of reusability, allowing you to combine several simiple features into more sosphisticated ones. Above you already saw `rand` and `sleep` -

```js
const rand = x =>
  Math.random() * x

const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
```

If we want to `throttle` each job, we can specialize `sleep` to ensure a minimum runtime -

```js
const throttle = (p, ms) =>
  Promise.all([ p, sleep(ms) ]).then(([ value, _ ]) => value)

async function jobQueued(x) {
  const close = await pool.open()
  // ensure job takes at least 3 seconds before freeing thread
  return throttle(job(x), 3000).then(close)
}

Promise.all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(jobQueued))
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```js
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
```

We can add some `console.log` messages to ensure things are running properly. And we will add a random `sleep` at the beginning of the job to show that the tasks can queue in any order without affecting the order of the result -

```js
async function jobQueued(x) {
  await sleep(rand(5000))
  console.log("queueing", x)
  const close = await pool.open()
  console.log("  sending", x)
  const result = await throttle(job(x), 3000).then(close)
  console.log("    received", result)
  return result
}

Promise.all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(jobQueued))
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

| console.log | thread 1 | thread 2 | thread 3 | thread 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| queueing 12 | ⌛ | ⌛ | ⌛ | ⌛ |
| sending 12 | **open** | ⌛ | ⌛ | ⌛ |
| queueing 9 | ↓ | ⌛ | ⌛ | ⌛ |
| sending 9 | ↓ | **open** | ⌛ | ⌛ |
| queueing 8 | ↓ | ↓ | ⌛ | ⌛ |
| sending 8 | ↓ | ↓ | **open** | ⌛ |
| queueing 4 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ⌛ |
| sending 4 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | **open** |
| queueing 10 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing 6 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing 7 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing 2 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing 11 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| received 120 | **closed** | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| sending 11 | **open** | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing 3 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing 5 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing 1 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| received 80 | ↓ | ↓ | **closed** | ↓ |
| sending 1 | ↓ | ↓ | **open** | ↓ |
| received 90 | ↓ | **closed** | ↓ | ↓ |
| sending 5 | ↓ | **open** | ↓ | ↓ |
| received 110 | **closed** | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| sending 3 | **open** | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| received 40 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | **closed** |
| sending 2 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | **open** |
| received 10 | ↓ | ↓ | **closed** | ↓ |
| sending 7 | ↓ | ↓ | **open** | ↓ |
| received 50 | ↓ | **closed** | ↓ | ↓ |
| sending 6 | ↓ | **open** | ↓ | ↓ |
| received 20 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | **closed** |
| sending 10 | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ | **open** |
| received 30 | **closed** | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| received 70 | ⌛ | ↓ | **closed** | ↓ |
| received 60 | ⌛ | **closed** | ⌛ | ↓ |
| received 100 | ⌛ | ⌛ | ⌛ | **closed** |

```js
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
```

Above, our `pool` was initialized with `size=4` so up to four jobs will run concurrently. After we see `sending` four times, a job must be completed and we see `received` before the next job begins. `queueing` can happen at any time. You may also notice `Pool` processes queued jobs using an efficient last-in-first-out (LIFO) order but the order of the result is maintained.

Moving on with our implementation, like our other functions, we can write `thread` in a simple way -

```js
const effect = f => x =>
  (f(x), x)

const thread = close =>
  [new Promise(r => { close = effect(r) }), close]

function main () {
  const [t, close] = thread()
  console.log("please wait...")
  setTimeout(close, 3000)
  return t.then(_ => "some result")
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
please wait...
(3 seconds later)
some result
```

And now we can use `thread` to write more sophisticated features like `Pool` -

```js
class Pool {
  constructor (size = 4) {
    Object.assign(this, { pool: new Set, stack: [], size })
  }
  open () {
    return this.pool.size < this.size
      ? this.deferNow()
      : this.deferStacked()
  }
  deferNow () {
    const [t, close] = thread()
    const p = t
      .then(_ => this.pool.delete(p))
      .then(_ => this.stack.length && this.stack.pop().close())
    this.pool.add(p)
    return close
  }
  deferStacked () {
    const [t, close] = thread()
    this.stack.push({ close })
    return t.then(_ => this.deferNow())
  }
}
```

And just like that your program is complete. In the functioning demo below, I condensed the definitions so we can see them all at once. Run the program to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
class Pool {
  constructor (size = 4) { Object.assign(this, { pool: new Set, stack: [], size }) }
  open () { return this.pool.size < this.size ? this.deferNow() : this.deferStacked() }
  deferNow () { const [t, close] = thread(); const p = t.then(_ => this.pool.delete(p)).then(_ => this.stack.length && this.stack.pop().close()); this.pool.add(p); return close }
  deferStacked () { const [t, close] = thread(); this.stack.push({ close }); return t.then(_ => this.deferNow()) }
}
const rand = x => Math.random() * x
const effect = f => x => (f(x), x)
const thread = close => [new Promise(r => { close = effect(r) }), close]
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
const throttle = (p, ms) => Promise.all([ p, sleep(ms) ]).then(([ value, _ ]) => value)

const myJob = x => sleep(rand(5000)).then(_ => x * 10)
const pool = new Pool(4)

async function jobQueued(x) {
  await sleep(rand(5000))
  console.log("queueing", x)
  const close = await pool.open()
  console.log("  sending", x)
  const result = await throttle(myJob(x), 3000).then(close)
  console.log("    received", result)
  return result
}

Promise.all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(jobQueued))
  .then(JSON.stringify)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Hopefully you learned something fun about JavaScript! If you enjoyed this, try expanding on `Pool` features. Maybe add a simple `timeout` function that ensures a job completes within a certain amount of time. Or maybe add a `retry` function that re-runs a job if it produces an error or times out. To see `Pool` applied to another problem, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67795491/633183). If you have any questions, I'm happy to assist :D

Comment: Your answer is fantastic! It is one of the best answers that I've seen. I apricate you for spending your time writing this complete answer.

Comment: @S.Hesam I'm delighted to share. Thanks for your encouraging comment :D

Answer (score 1):

First modify your code so it calls a function called `waitAndFetch()`. You'll be passing in the URL plus the index value of that element in the array (0,1,2,3...):

```
async function getReports(reportIDs) {
    const urls = reportIDs.map(id => `https://api.data.com/api/v1/report/${id}/?include_datasets=true`);
    
    const requests = urls.map((url,i) => waitAndFetch);
    
    const responses = await Promise.all(requests).catch(err => console.error(err));
    return responses;
}
```

Next, create a function that simply returns a promise that resolves in 1000 x the index value milliseconds (0, 1sec, 2sec, 3sec...):

```
const wait = (i) => {
    const ms = i * 1000;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
};
```

Now write waitAndFetch. It will call wait(), but won't care about its return value. It only cares that it has to wait for it to resolve:

```
const waitAndFetch = async (url, i) => {
    await wait(i);
    const response = fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'api-key': key }
    });
    return response.json();
};
```

Comment: This makes each request `wait` one second before `fetch`ing but all `requests` still begin at the same time. If you want to wait one second before *each* request, you could use a simple `for` loop. Something like `const result = []; for (const url of urls) { await wait(); result.push(await fetch(url)) } return result`

Comment: Thank you, @Thankyou. I coded a fix by fixing the code

Answer (score -1):

I think the best thing to do is use a sleep function.

```
async function sleep() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 300));
}

await sleep()
```

Comment: What if the API doesn't come back for 400ms? 10000? 60000?

Comment: No matter the point is that you wait between every call not that you wait until it is back