# Why do I get an Unhandled Promise Rejection with await Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

This is the general structure of my code:

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const asyncActions = []

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))

      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        asyncActions.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000)))
      }
    }

    await Promise.all(asyncActions)
    console.log('all resolved')
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log('caught error', e)
  }
})()
```

I expect this to catch any rejections happening in `asyncActions` because they should be handled by `Promise.all()`, but somehow they are unhandled? The console shows the following:

```
(node:9460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9460) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:9460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:9460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
...

(node:9460) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
(node:9460) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 2)
...
```

Why are they not handled by `Promise.all()` and then caught in the catch block?

I also noticed that when I replace both the `new Promise(...)` with just `Promise.resolve()` and `Promise.reject()` respectively it catches the errors. Why is that? Aren't both variants asynchronous and thus should work the same way?

Comment: The first "batch" of promises get rejected before you get to the next batch. Remember that promises don't "start" when they are `await`-ed or similar. Promises already mark something that's started. So, you give `Promise.all()` a bunch of already rejected promises - each of those would have logged a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way we detect non-handling of promise rejections in Node.js is using a *heuristic*.

When a promise is rejected we give the user a chance to still attach a listener (synchronously) - if they don't we assume it's not handled and cause an `unhandledRejection`. This is because:

- It's impossible (as in the halting problem) to know if a user will ever attach such a handler in the future.
- In the vast majority of cases it's sufficient, since it's best-practice to always immediately attach listeners.

So - you need to always add the catch listeners synchronously in order to avoid the unhandled rejections.

You can also (in your non-contrived case) just opt out by adding an empty catch listener in a fork:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const asyncActions = []

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))

      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000));
        p.catch(() => {}); // suppress unhandled rejection
        asyncActions.push(p)
      }
    }

    await Promise.all(asyncActions)
    console.log('all fulfilled')
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log('caught error', e)
  }
})()
```

---

- Fun historical tidbit #1: we considered using GC to detect unhandledRejections - people found it more confusing.
- Fun historical tidbit #2: Chrome does the same thing but actually removes the messages retrospectively if you add a listener.
- Fun historical tidbit #3: This heuristic originated in bluebird in 2013. I [talk about it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGpmUyFnyuQ).

Comment: Alternative way to solve it - don't produce the promises until they can be `await`-ed. So, `asyncActions` should be an array of thunks producing promises, and then you'd have `await Promise.all(asyncActions.map(fn => fn()))`

Comment: @VLAZ yes though that has very different behaviour - ideally I agree you don't want to produce promises without listening to their rejections but I assumed the OP had that as a constraint :)

Comment: This worked, but can you please explain what exactly does `.catch(() => {})`? How does `Promise.all` still know that something got rejected when it was already caught? And how does the error message make it through to the catch block when the `.catch` just returns an empty object?

Comment: @DaDo the error isn't coming from the `Promise.all` it's coming from Node itself. When you create a promise and reject it Node.js will keep track of it - and if no rejection handler is attached it emits an unhandledRejection. Adding a `.catch` (or `.then`) to a promise "forks" it, the promise `asyncActions` is getting is the same one (and not the one after the `.catch` - that is it's not mutative)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Ok, but why do we have to attach the `.catch` in the next line instead of just doing `asyncActions.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000)).catch(() => {}))` (this doesn't work)? What's the difference to your example?

Comment: Because that passes the Promise.all the "forked" version which has a catch handler attached to it already that silences the error.

Answer (score 4):

**where it goes wrong**

This is happening because at least one promise is rejected *before* getting to `Promise.all` If you adjust the timeout of the rejected promises to `5000`, you will see the `catch` block act as intended -

```js
(async () => {
  console.log("please wait...")
  try {
    const asyncActions = []

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))

      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        asyncActions.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 5000, "FOO")))
      }
    }

    await Promise.all(asyncActions)
    console.log('all resolved')
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log('caught error', e)
  }
})()
```

```
please wait...
error caught FOO
```

**capturing the error**

Above, this works because all `asyncActions` are still pending by the time they get to `Promise.all`. However this is fragile as we cannot guarantee this would be the case. Benjamin's proposed answer is to swallow the error, but I think we could improve by bubbling the error up -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise((resolve, _) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const myTask = x =>
  sleep(30).then(_ => Promise.reject(x))


;(async () => {
  console.log("please wait...")
  try {
    // outer promise
    await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const actions = []

      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        await sleep(1000)
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          // reject outer promise if this task fails
          actions(myTask(j).catch(reject))
        }
      }

      const result = await Promise.all(actions)
      console.log('all done')
      resolve(result) // <- resolve outer
    })
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log('caught error', e)
  }
})()
```

**separate effects**

Above, adding an outer promise works, but `await new Promise(...)` is a bit of an anti-pattern. By moving the effect (`console.log`) and the error handler outside of your task, your code cleans up considerably -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise((resolve, _) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

async function myTask(i, j) {
  await sleep(300)
  if (Math.random() > .95)
    throw [i, j]
  return i + j
}

function queuedTasks() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const actions = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      await sleep(1000)
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        actions.push(myTask(i,j).catch(reject))
    }
    Promise.all(actions).then(resolve)
  })
}

console.log("please wait...")
queuedTasks()
  .then(results => console.log("all done", results)) // <- receives result
  .catch(console.error) // <- handles error
```

Above, this example has a 5% reject chance for `myTask`. Run it several times to see both a resolved and a rejected result -

```js
// resolved
all done [0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4]
```

```js
// rejected
Error: [1,2]
```

**Pool**

You could stop there but I think there's still room for improvement here. By reading the code, I can see the intention is to batch the promises three (3) at a time, waiting one (1) second in between each batch -

```js
  // ...
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ...
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  // three batches
      await sleep(1000)            // wait one second
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++)  // then run batch
        actions.push(myTask(...))  // add each task
    }
    // ...
    Promise.all(actions).then(resolve)
  })
```

This design will start three tasks every second, regardless of whether the running tasks are finished. It is a primitive level of control at best and at worst it's a lot of boilerplate to copy every time you want to do queued/throttled tasks.

One solution is to design a data structure that can do these things for you in a reusable way. Let's take a look at `Pool` -

```js
// create pool with 3 "threads"
const pool = new Pool(3)

async function queuedTask(i, j) {
  const close = await pool.open()     // wait for pool thread to open
  return throttle(myTask(i, j), 1000) // throttle task by one second minimum
    .finally(close)                   // close thread upon completion
}

// ...
```

Now you can write a simple loop, this time using `queuedTask` -

```js
// ...
const actions = []
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    actions.push(queuedTask(i,j))
  }
}

console.log("please wait...")
Promise.all(actions)
  .then(JSON.stringify)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

In the table below, we can see how `Pool(3)` will carry out the tasks -

| task | `(i,j)` | thread 1 | thread 2 | thread 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| queueing | `(0,0)` | ⌛ | ⌛ | ⌛ |
| running | `(0,0)` | **open** | ⌛ | ⌛ |
| queueing | `(0,1)` | ↓ | ⌛ | ⌛ |
| running | `(0,1)` | ↓ | **open** | ⌛ |
| queueing | `(0,2)` | ↓ | ↓ | ⌛ |
| running | `(0,2)` | ↓ | ↓ | **open** |
| queueing | `(1,0)` | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing | `(1,1)` | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing | `(1,2)` | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing | `(2,0)` | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing | `(2,1)` | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| queueing | `(2,2)` | ↓ | ↓ | ↓ |
| finished | `(0,0)` | **closed** | ↓ | ↓ |
| running | `(2,2)` | **open** | ↓ | ↓ |
| finished | `(0,2)` | ↓ | ↓ | **closed** |
| running | `(2,1)` | ↓ | ↓ | **open** |
| finished | `(0,1)` | ↓ | **closed** | ↓ |
| running | `(2,0)` | ↓ | **open** | ↓ |
| finished | `(2,1)` | ↓ | ↓ | **closed** |
| running | `(1,2)` | ↓ | ↓ | **open** |
| finished | `(2,0)` | ↓ | **closed** | ↓ |
| running | `(1,1)`) | ↓ | **open** | ↓ |
| finished | `(2,2)` | **closed** | ↓ | ↓ |
| running | `(1,0)` | **open** | ↓ | ↓ |
| finished | `(1,2)` | ↓ | ↓ | **closed** |
| finished | `(1,0)` | **closed** | ↓ | ⌛ |
| finished | `(1,1)` | ⌛ | **closed** | ⌛ |

To learn more about this approach, see `Pool` implemented in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628301/633183). Expand the snippet below and run it several times to see both resolved and rejected outputs -

```js
class Pool {
  constructor (size = 4) { Object.assign(this, { pool: new Set, stack: [], size }) }
  open () { return this.pool.size < this.size ? this.deferNow() : this.deferStacked() }
  deferNow () { const [t, close] = thread(); const p = t.then(_ => this.pool.delete(p)).then(_ => this.stack.length && this.stack.pop().close()); this.pool.add(p); return close }
  deferStacked () { const [t, close] = thread(); this.stack.push({ close }); return t.then(_ => this.deferNow()) }
}
const rand = x => Math.random() * x
const effect = f => x => (f(x), x)
const thread = close => [new Promise(r => { close = effect(r) }), close]
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
const throttle = (p, ms) => Promise.all([ p, sleep(ms) ]).then(([ value, _ ]) => value)

async function myTask(i, j) {
  await sleep(rand(2000))
  if (Math.random() > .95)
    throw Error([i, j])
  return i + j
}

async function queuedTask(i, j) {
  const close = await pool.open()
  return throttle(myTask(i, j), 1000).finally(close)
}

const pool = new Pool(3)
const actions = []
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    actions.push(queuedTask(i,j))
  }
}

console.log("please wait...")
Promise.all(actions)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```js
// resolved
[0,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4]
```

```js
// rejected
Error: [1,2]
```