# Issue Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise, promise.all

I want to declare an array of empty promises 
then resolve them manually, but it is not working ?

```
const tab = [1]
let promises = tab.map(e => new Promise(() => { }))
setTimeout(() => {
  promises[0] = Promise.resolve()
}, 3000);
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(e => console.log("finished"))
```

**I DO NOT WANT** to do it like this :

```
const tab = [1]
let promises = tab.map(e => new Promise((resolve) => { 
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve()
  }, 3000);
}))

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(e => console.log("finished"))
```

Comment: What's the use case behind this, can help in understanding what you want to exactly achieve?

Comment: The resolve doesn’t resolve with anything? Also I think if you’re using `Promise.resolve` the promise constructor is not needed.

Comment: Please provide the expected delays and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the closest you can get:

```
const tab = [1]
let resolves = []
let promises = tab.map(e => new Promise((resolve) => {
   resolves.push(resolve)
}))
setTimeout(() => {
  resolves[0]()
}, 3000);
Promise.all(promises).then(e => console.log("finished"))
```

Comment: I’m still confused, each individual promise resolves undefined?

Comment: You nailed it 

Comment: This pattern is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a technique using a reusable `deferred` function that allows you to externally control a promise. We extend both `resolve` *and* `reject` functionality, allowing better control for the caller. This is a somewhat unconventional pattern but there are advantages to exploiting promises in this way. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628301/633183) for an detailed example -

```js
function deferred () {
  let resolve, reject, promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    resolve = res; reject = rej
  })
  return { promise, resolve, reject }
}

const tasks = [ deferred(), deferred(), deferred() ] // 3 "deferrred" objects

Promise.all(tasks.map(t => t.promise)).then(console.log, console.error)

setTimeout(_ => tasks[0].resolve("one"), 1000)
setTimeout(_ => tasks[1].resolve("two"), 2000)
setTimeout(_ => tasks[2].resolve("three"), 3000)
```