# How to execute a Promise every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, promise, google-colaboratory, webcam

I am using google colab to capture webcam video. I am using Promises to start and end the video on click. I want to stop capturing video every 5 seconds using a Promise.

```
  // start recording
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    capture.onclick = resolve;
  });
  recorder.start();
  capture.replaceWith(stopCapture);
  // use a promise to tell it to stop recording
  
  // I want to stop recording every 5 seconds here instead of on click
  await new Promise((resolve) => stopCapture.onclick = resolve);

  recorder.stop();
```

Comment: "stop capturing video every 5 seconds" doesn't make sense. After the video is stopped, why would you need to stop it again?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 sorry If I worded this wrong or did not give enough information. Basically what I am trying to do is record a video for 5 seconds stop save that then record again for 5 seconds and repeat.

Comment: Sounds like you want to [resolve a promise with an event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68135685/633183)...

Answer (score 0):

Use a setTimeout in your promise to have it resolve in exactly 5 seconds

```
const FIVE_SECONDS_IN_MS = 5000;

var fiveSecondPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, FIVE_SECONDS_IN_MS)
})

fiveSecondPromise.then(done => {
  // hits here in 5 seconds
})
```

Comment: The question says "**every** 5 seconds" so it's possible they're looking for `setInterval`, not just `setTimeout`.  But it also says "stop capturing", which is not really a repeatable event.   Could just be a language thing.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah I am trying to set an interval to where  it will record for 5 seconds and then stop recording and then start record again

Comment: @Lukas Sorensen So would I just put the stop capture on click in here this block of code fiveSecondPromise.then(done => { // hits here in 5 seconds //insert here })